# Graph returned an error: (# 100) Only owners of the URL have the ability to specify the picture, name, thumbnail or description params

Tags: facebook, api

I'm trying to publish a post to fbk Page.

1) The fbk Page owner is not me, so through facebook Business Manager I got the role of administrator

2) In Facebook Developer I've created new fbk app and the settings have been defined

3) In https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ I've requested the User Token (by flagging all permissions), and extended its duration (button Extend in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ )

4) In https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ I've requested the Page Token and extended its duration too

5) I’ve verified the domain in https://business.facebook.com/ > Business Manager settings > Brand Safety tab > Domains > Add > example.it and I verified it using HTML file

6) I’ve assigned the page in https://business.facebook.com/ > Business Manager settings > Brand Safety tab > Domains > select domain example.it > Pages > Assign page > EXAMPLE

Finally this is the code used on my website to posted news. Without 'picture', 'link' and 'description' seems to work fine and return the post id:

“Posted with id: 1234561425917649_1234565412555243”

```
$page_access_token = “XYZ123”;
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'            => '123456789012345',  
    'app_secret'            => '1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a”
    'default_access_token'      => $page_access_token,
    'default_graph_version'     => 'v3.2'
]);
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', [
                                        'message'       => 'Text - message',
                                        'name'          => ‘Text - name’,
                                        'picture'       => 'http://www.esample.com/images/logo.png',
                                        'link'          => 'http://www.example.com/page.php',
                                        'description'   => 'Text - description,
                                    ]);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

Otherwise provides the error "Graph returned an error: (# 100) Only owners of the URL have the ability to specify the picture, name, thumbnail or description params."

Comment: Did you manage to get this working ? I am struggling with the same thing. Had added ownership and verified domain already posting link works fine, adding "picture" breaks with same error as the one you get

Answer (score 0):

This is mandatory to verify domain using administrator login through domain verification in facebook business manager through one of three given option

1. Html tag
2. Html file upload
3. DNS verification

See documentation

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification
ping me if you have still isuue.

Comment: I have done this and still doesn't work